# body tag causes CLS issue on Lighthouse and Page Insight

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, seo, lighthouse, cumulative-layout-shift

so guys i have some problem on Lighthoust data but CLS is the most poor score on my lighthouse metrics data, and i just figure it out, that the metrics give me a detail about CLS that the most contibute on my CLS metrics is the body tag, i don't know why it can happen, for me as a beginer its kind like something uncommon issue, i tried to find out that not found the same problem like me. And i've tried to remove all attribute on body tag but it still got same issue. this is the sample of the metrics data. I'm using nuxt btw this is my code base

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

1. [metrics image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP1xl.png)
2. [CLS detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRk2u.png)
3. [body tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmQpv.png)

i tried to make the CLS atleast under 1.0 point

Comment: it's hard to help you with code when you have none

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX thank you for your answer, i just add the code, i think its not enough to find out but, that all i can share here :(

Comment: yeah, you're right, doesn't help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Update]

I solved the problem by reducing the dynamically inject code to the HTML that caused CLS.